# What are options in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, terminology, hierarchical-rl, semi-mdp, options

According to a lecture (week 10) about Reinforcement Learning [[1]](https://nptel.ac.in/courses/106/106/106106143/), the concept of an **option** allows searching the state space of an agent much faster. The lecture was hard to follow because many new terms were introduced in a short time. For me, the concept of an option sounds a bit like **skills** [[2]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608008000701), which are used for describing high-level actions as well.

Are skills an improvement over options that includes the trajectory, or are both the same?

I'm asking for a certain reason. Normal deep reinforcement learning has the problem that the agent comes very often to a dead end, for example, in Montezuma's Revenge played at the Atari emulator. And the options framework promises to overcome the issue. But the concept sounds a bit too esoteric, and apart from the Nptel lecture, nobody else has explained the idea. So, is it useful at all?

Comment: what is the difference between options and learning larger code fragments for a domains specific language (DSL)? ref: dreamcoder https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtu0aSTDE2I&t=1167s

Comment: what is a modern survey of options ("temporal abstraction in reinforcement learning") or an example of a modern application of it? (especially with a good background section to learn options and some modern model that uses it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An **option** is a generalization of the concept of action. The concept of an *option* (or [macro-action](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.2402&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) was introduced in the context of reinforcement learning in the paper [Between MDPs and semi-MDPs: A framework for temporal abstraction in reinforcement learning](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370299000521) (1998) by Richard Sutton et al., so that to capture the idea that certain actions are composed of other sub-actions. Section 2 of the mentioned paper formally defines the concept of an option, which is a tuple composed of an **initiation set**, a **policy**, and a **termination condition/set**.

The authors of the mentioned paper give examples of options

> Examples of options include *picking up an object, going to lunch, and traveling to a distant city*, as well as primitive actions such as *muscle twitches* and *joint torques*.

The option *picking up an object, going to lunch, and traveling to a distant city* is composed of other sub-actions (e.g. *picking up an object*), but is itself an action (or macro-action). A primitive action (e.g. *joint torques*) is itself an option.

A set of options defined over an MDP constitutes a [**semi-Markov decision process (SMDP)**](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/eb7f/25d8cecf31fae319cf94030966c88f5a8bb4.pdf), which are MDPs where the time between actions is not constant but it is variable. In other words, a semi-MDP (SMDP) is an extension of the concept of MDP that is used to deal with problems where there are actions of different levels of abstraction.  For example, consider a footballer that needs to [take a freekick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_free_kick). The action "take a freekick" involves a sequence of other actions, like "run towards the ball", "look at the wall", etc. The action "take a freekick" takes a variable number of time steps (which depends on the other sub-actions).

Semi-MDPs are thus used to deal with such problems that involve actions of different levels of abstraction. **Hierarchical reinforcement learning** (HRL) is a generalization (or extension) of reinforcement learning where the environment is modeled as a semi-MDP.

Curiously, certain models that have won the [RoboCup](https://www.robocup.org/) (the famous AI football) context are based on the concept of semi-MDPs, options and HRL. See e.g. [WrightEagleBASE](https://github.com/wrighteagle2d/wrighteaglebase), which use the [MAXQ-OP (MAXQ online planning) algorithm](https://aijunbai.github.io/publications/TIST15-Bai.pdf).

Semi-MDPs can be converted to MDPs. The picture below (which is a screenshot of figure 1 of the mentioned paper that introduces the "options framework" in RL) illustrates the relationship between semi-MDPs and MDPs.

[image]

The empty circles (in the middle) are options, while the black circles (at the top) are primitive actions (which are themselves options).

In the paper [Reinforcement learning of motor skills with policy gradients](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.142.8735) mentioned in the question, apparently, the term skill is not formally defined. However, I suppose that skills can be represented as options.

Comment: For the last part, I would assume "skills" has close to the natural language meaning, and refers to learning effective policies (policies that perform a task well).

Comment: what is the difference between options and learning larger code fragments for a domains specific language (DSL)? ref: dreamcoder https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtu0aSTDE2I&t=1167s

Comment: what is a modern survey of options ("temporal abstraction in reinforcement learning") or an example of a modern application of it? (especially with a good background section to learn options and some modern model that uses it)

Comment: @CharlieParker Please, ask your questions in their separate post. One question per post. For each post, provide the necessary context to understand the question.